# Superpose a subscript and the rest of a formula

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I have a formula in the equation environment that goes like

`Foo = \bigcup_{x \in veryveryveryverylongdescription} Bar(x)`

Because the state space's description is long, the `Bar(x)` is rejected far away from the `\bigcup`. I would like `Bar(x)` to be right next to the union symbol, above the description.

Can this be done cleanly? Or shall I try to have with two equations, some vspace and horizontal space shifts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\smashoperator` macro from the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \mathit{Foo} =
   \smashoperator{\bigcup_{x \in \text{long text}}} \operatorname{Bar}(x) \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest to try also `\smashoperator[r]{...}`; this depends on the "long text": if not very long, pushing it under the equals sign may be OK, but not if it goes beyond it.